# Concatenate a variable in a url

Tags: javascript

I'm using the wikipedia and Google APis.

When I select a city, I want to display the page from wikipedia. I have some problems on putting the city variable in wiki search url.

The city is in myVariable var.

```
    **var myVariable = locality;** 
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse
&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page= + myVariable + &callback=?",
```

I know that in javascript we make the concatenation with + but I guess I'm doing something wrong there and I can't figure out what.

Comment: What do you think `" + foo + "` does? What about `" ++++ foo ++++ "`?

Comment: You could use the technique called "debugging". Instead of sitting around staring at your code and wondering why it doesn't work, or wasting other people's time, in "debugging" you actually do things yourself to figure out why it doesn't work. For instance, you could assign the url string you are creating to a variable, and then examine it in a **debugger**. If you don't know what that is, find out right away before you code another line. This has the advantage that you can actually solve your own problems instead of having to post to SO every time.

Comment: ^ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Debugging_JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page=" + myVariable + "&callback=?"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this...

```
url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse
&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page=" + myVariable + "&callback=?"
```

Comment: Please [edit] in an explanation of why/how this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they are not as easy to learn from as code with an explanation. Without an explanation it takes considerably more time and effort to understand what was being done, the changes made to the code, if the code answers the question, etc.  The explanation is important both for people attempting to learn from the answer and those evaluating the answer to see if it is valid, or worth up voting. In this instance, it would be easy to have said that the OP is missing two `"` marks.